# Create Access reports from Form and save as PDF

Tags: forms, ms-access, pdf, ms-access-2010

Im currently using an Access database to create alot of reports - the report is made using a Query as a source, in the Query i use a Form as criteria so that the open page in the Form is the data used in the report. 
Then I save the report as a PDF and click in the form to run the next set of data. 
That is very time consuming when i have over 500 reports to make. So is there a way to make a function, a VBA or macro to run through all pages in the form and save each report as a PDF?

My form is named NorwF, the query is NorwQ and the report is NorwRap

I hope that makes sense and that there is a faster way to make this projekt run smoothly.

Comment: Yes, there is, using `DoCmd.OutputTo` and setting `OutputFormat` to `acFormatPDF`. However, I'm not going to write the entire function for you. You will either have to try to write it yourself, or pay someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you place a button on the form, this code behind should work:

```
Dim rst      As DAO.Recordset

Dim strReport        As String
Dim strReportFile    As String

strReport = "NorwRap"
'Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
Set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordSet("NorwQ")  'use the query
Do While rst.EOF = False

  strReportFile = rst!ID & ".pdf"   ' give report name based on field name
  DoCmd.OpenReport strReport,acViewPreview , , "id = " & rst!ID
  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReport, acFormatPDF, strOutFile
  DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport

  rst.MoveNext

Loop
```

Comment: I have triede getting this to run now, i have change te strReportFile to "strReportFile = rst!Property_no_ & ".pdf"  ' give report name based on field name
  DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acViewPreview, , "id=" & rst!Property_no_! but when i click the button the PDF that it wants to save is NorwRap.pdf and the property no is not added so it's just an empty report. Im using Property_no_ as the field name from the report

Comment: I have the code setup to use current reocrds in the form - see my mod to the code if you want all reocrds from the query.

Comment: You  can feed the report a single  pk "ID" or you can  use the property_no - it should not matter which one you use. As long as the list you feed the recordset loop has "some"  value that can be used to restrict the report to the one ID or Property_no it should work. If Property_no is a string/text column, then you have to surround the value with quotes (a single quote is fine).